# Using BeautifulSoup to extract parts of string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 to parse a html document and extract data.

I'd like to get the time values from this tag:

```
<span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:Arial;color:#666666"> 20 min <b>Start time: </b> 10 min <b>Other time: </b> 0 min</span>
```

I.E: 20 min, 10 min

Comment: Extracting the parts using substring. This feels wrong however. Ideally I'd like to get a text node of the content.

Comment: I mean can you give us the code you already have and explain whatis working and what is not. Also a link to the webiste you try to crawl would help alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import Tag

soup = BeautifulSoup("<span style=\"font-size:9.0pt;font-family:Arial;color:#666666\"> 20 min <b>Start time: </b> 10 min <b>Other time: </b> 0 min</span>")
span = soup.find('span')
for e in span.contents:
 if type(e) is Tag:
   print "found a tag:", e.name
 else:
   print "found text:", e
```

Output:

```
found text:  20 min
found a tag: b
found text:  10 min
found a tag: b
found text:  0 min
```

Comment: I ended up using span.contents and from there I could grab the values from the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ss = """<span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:Arial;color:#666666"> 20 min <b>Start time:     </b> 10 min <b>Other time: </b> 0 min</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(ss)
timetext = soup.span.text
start_time = timetext.split("Start time:")[1].split("min")[0].strip()
```

***I've left the extraction of other_time as an exercise for you!***